# Getting error "Cannot find module" when using import with Node.js 14.1.0

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, import, es6-modules

When trying to import like this:

```
import { port } from './config';
```

I am getting this error:

**Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/USER/PROJECT/src/config'**

But when I try this import it works fine:

```
import { port } from './config.js';
```

Content of config.js:

```
export const port = 3000;
export const hostname = localhost;
```

"type" is set to "module" in my package.json, using Node.js v14.1.0

So, how can I use extension-less import?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Run node with this flag by default

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node index.js
```

---

At the end of your config.js, export your module like this:

```js
 module.exports = { port, hostname };
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for anwser, but my question was how to use extension-less import with import/export, not require/module.exports.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Can you post your package.json file? I replicated a similar environment and the results worked out well for your node version. 
Do you mean import { port } from 'config' ?